# Джойстик Unity Прыжок

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Как сделать так чтобы при прыжке он прыгал не бесконечно, а к примеру 1 раз в 3 секунды?

```
void Update() {
if(joystick.Vertical > 0.5 && isWallFront && !isGrounded)
        {
            if(transform.rotation.y == 0)
            {
                Jump();
            }
            soundeffector.PlayJumpSound();
        }
        else if (joystick.Vertical > 0.5 && isGrounded)
        {
            Jump();
        }
}
public void Jump()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpHeight;//Прыжок
        soundeffector.PlayJumpSound();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно, чтобы игрок стабильно прыгал раз в три секунды, то:

```
private IEnumerator () {
    while (true) {
        Jump();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}

public void Jump () {...}
```

Но судя по вашему коду, вам нужно сделать так, чтобы игрок **не** мог прыгать **чаще** чем раз в три секунды. Тогда вы можете просто завести счетчик времени.

```
private float lastTick = 0;
private const int MinJumpDelay = 3;

private void Update() {
    if  (lastTick >= MinJumpDelay) {
        // Можно прыгать
    }
    lastTick += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Я бы изменил ваш код следующим образом:

```
private float lastTick = 0;
private const int MinJumpDelay = 3;

private void Update() {
    if  (lastTick >= MinJumpDelay) {
        if (canJump()) {
            Jump();
        }
        lastTick += Time.deltaTime;
    }

private bool canJump () {
    return joystick.Vertical > 0.5f && 
            (isGrounded || isWallFront && transform.rotation.y > 0);
}
```

Comment: Не работает, прыгает такчже бесконечно

Comment: @Виталий Вы написали, что не прыгает. Какое именно условие не срабатывает: Условие с проверкой тиков или с проверкой canJump()?

Comment: Игрок не прыгает, то есть не выполняется метод jump()

Comment: @Виталий Еще раз спрашиваю: до какой строки доходит выполнение функции Update? Я говорю про *последний* мой вариант кода

Answer (score -1):

У меня вот так получилось

```
void Update(){
        if (lastTick >= MinJumpDelay)
        {
            if (canJump())
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }
}
private bool canJump()
    {
        return joystick.Vertical > 0.5f &&
                (isGrounded || isWallFront && transform.rotation.y > 0);
    }
    public void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpHeight;//Прыжок
            soundeffector.PlayJumpSound();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "У меня вот так получилось" -- во-первых, не у вас. Это код из моего ответа. Во-вторых, не получилось. Этот код не может работать, потому что в своем ответе я забыл строку `lastTick += Time.deltaTime`. С этим кодом у вас никто никуда не будет прыгать. Зачем вы вообще опубликовали еще ответ с моим кодом?

Comment: Я просто первый раз на сайте, думал так виднее. Извините пожалуйста

Comment: У меня теперь игрок не прыгает

Comment: Советую вам удалить этот ответ. Если мой ответ вам помог, вы можете проголосовать за него, нажав стрелочку вверх или принять его, нажав галочку. Возможно для этих действий у вас не хватит репутации. В таком случае вы можете сделать это позже, когда наберете ее. Я знаю, что игрок не прыгает, я про это написал в первом комментарии. Я уже исправил **свой** ответ. Там новый код. Попробуйте его.

Comment: Все ровно не прыгает